# Oracle 12 - Reset a sequence Column with row_number() over Partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table (with order by product, seq):

```
product     group       seq
10             5         1
10             11        5
11             2         3
11             4         4
11             24        5
```

As you can see because of some delete statments I need to reset the seq column and have a seq from 1 for every product/group like this:

```
productnr     group     seq
10             5         1
10             11        2
11             2         1
11             4         2
11             24        3
```

I tried to create a new counter with this code:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.product order by  t.product ) newSeq
from table t
order by t.product, t.seq;
```

and the result was like this:

```
product     group     seq      newSeq
10             5         1         1
10             11        5         2
11             2         3         1
11             4         4         2
11             24        5         3
```

But when I try it with Update I get ora-00907:

```
update table a set a.seq= 
(
    select row_number() over (partition by z.product order by  z.product ) newSeq
    from table z
    where z.product = a.product and z.seq= a.seq
    order by z.product, z.seq
);
```

I think the error is because of "`order by z.product, z.seq`" in Subselect. I can not remove it, because the newSeq must be based on old Seq and without it the newSub might be wrong.

**Update 1:**

Hier is the example without orderby:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.product order by  t.product ) newSeq
from table t
order by t.product, t.seq;
```

result:

```
product       group     seq        newSeq
10             11        5           1 
10             5         1           2
11             4         4           1
11             2         3           2
11             24        5           3
```

As you can see the newSeq is not based On old Seq without order by. It means when product 5/group 11 has a greather seq than the same product/group 5, the new Seq should be like that as well.

Comment: In your case, IMO it's better to drop column `seq`, or just forget about it - the annoying mistracking- and generate it dynamically when you want.

Comment: As I wrote, the order is important and cannot be removed.

Comment: uhm, I talked about `seq` not your order, and if you cannot removed `seq` then just forget it, and generate it dynamically when you need to select/ fetch data from your table

Comment: This construction `partition by t.product order by  t.product` suggest that you should probably re-read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) of the analytic order by clause. You apparently try to enforce the order in a wrong place (with the query order by clause). Note also that your approach with correlated subquery will **not provide expected result** as you correlate the `seq` in the subquery leading to every new `seq` to be `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement and correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column to efficiently self-join:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY product
           ORDER BY ROWNUM  -- or ORDER BY seq
         ) AS newSeq
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.rid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET seq = src.newSeq;
```

*(Note: You do **NOT** need an `ORDER BY` expression appended to the `SELECT` statement as it will have no practical effect as the order of the source query is irrelevant during the `MERGE` and could make the `SELECT` statement less efficient if the ordering is applied and the SQL engine does unnecessary work.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( product, "GROUP", seq ) AS
SELECT 10,  5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10,  1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,  2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,  4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 24, 5 FROM DUAL
```

Then results in:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

> | PRODUCT | GROUP | SEQ |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10 | 5 | 1 |
> | 10 | 1 | 2 |
> | 11 | 2 | 1 |
> | 11 | 4 | 2 |
> | 11 | 24 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=995cdce3822baba10c141fb840578665)*

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

Before:

```
SQL> select * From test order by product, seq;

   PRODUCT        GRP        SEQ
---------- ---------- ----------
        10          5          2
        10         11          5
        11          2          3
        11          4          4
        11         24          7
```

Update:

```
SQL> update test t set
  2    t.seq = (select x.rn
  3             from (select a.product,
  4                          a.seq,
  5                          row_number() over (partition by a.product
  6                                             order by a.product, a.seq) rn
  7                   from test a
  8                  ) x
  9             where x.product = t.product
 10               and x.seq = t.seq
 11            );

5 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test order by product, seq;

   PRODUCT        GRP        SEQ
---------- ---------- ----------
        10          5          1
        10         11          2
        11          2          1
        11          4          2
        11         24          3

SQL>
```

Comment: No. Because I need "ORDER BY z.product, z.seq" in Sub select .

Comment: You **must be kidding**. What prevents you to add A.PRODUCT into ROW_NUMBER's ORDER BY clause?

Comment: I mean the second order by.  Not in Over().

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. **Result** - unless I'm wrong - shows that query I posted does what you wanted. If that's so, which "second order by"? What does it have to do with it?

Comment: Whatever. I you want, modify code I posted (the UPDATE statement) and that should be OK as far as problem you described is concerned (Oracle error).